# Cross platform paint program for web browsers and Mac devices

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, paint

I need to implement a paint type program that will run on all major browsers as well as can be packaged as an app on the iPad/iPhone. After some investigation I have learned the following facts (correct me if any are wrong):

1. Javascript is entirely too slow to handle an app of this type by itself
2. HTML5 seems like a good solution, it has a canvas tag and everything and can easily be packaged into a UIWebView for a Cocoa app. However, I need to be able to reach the majority market for web users, which unfortunately includes most IE users who aren't using the public beta for IE 9.
3. Flash vs. Apple

Right now I'm debating just making two completely separate apps, one in OpenGL ES for iPad/iPhone and another in something like Flash for web browsers. I was just wondering if anyone had an immediate solutions in mind to make one app instead?

Answer (score 4):

I'd question the accuracy of your first point (Javascript is too slow).  Since it's possible to [run Quake II in pure Javascript](http://code.google.com/p/quake2-gwt-port/), it's likely that your paint application is less resource-intensive and thus could also run.  Of course, one could ask how much optimisation effort and/or experience is required to write performant Javascript of this standard - I can't give you an answer there.

But I'm certainly sure that it's *possible* to get enough performance out of Javascript to implement such a paint tool, in any modern browser.  That doesn't preclude the other options, though; using JS along with HTML 5 sounds like the ideal solution here for "out of the box" cross-platform compatibility.